# Handle font size for multiple screen size windows 8 metro apps

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a text of font size 14.
On smaller screens it's visible but on bigger screens it becomes smaller.
How do I handle this?
On android we have `SP` which adjust the font size according to the screens.
Is there anything similar to this in windows 8 ?

Comment: check out this thread on the MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/659e1e95-9013-4644-a3a4-896335dec8ef - ViewBox may be your answer, if indeed that's the behavior you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do exactly what you want.

```
<Viewbox>
    <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.. If you are a MS guy could you please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14337623/468724

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using XAML?

So, you should start with something like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <x:Double x:Key="MyFontSize" />
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Name="StandardText">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource MyFontSize}" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource StandardText}">Hello World</TextBlock>
```

Then in your code behind have something like this:

```
Double _FontSize;
if (Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value
    == Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.FullScreenPortrait)
{
    // based on portrait
    if (this.RenderSize.Height > 2000)
        _FontSize = 30;
    if (this.RenderSize.Height > 1000)
        _FontSize = 20;
    else
        _FontSize = 10;
}
else
{
    // based on landscape
    if (this.RenderSize.Height > 1500)
        _FontSize = 30;
    if (this.RenderSize.Height > 1000)
        _FontSize = 20;
    else
        _FontSize = 10;
}
this.Resources["MyFontSize"] = _FontSize;
```

Whatever you detect when your app loads will always remain unless the user changes monitors on you!

Comment: Actually the screen size will change if you move the metro (store app) between displays when you have multiple monitors.

Comment: Stunning; I came to the same conclusion just yesterday. Maybe I was reading your comment in my mind (mental StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1):

I was doing a research on this.
I came to know 2 different things.
One is View Box and the other is logical DPI.

Comment: I tried using ViewBox in XAML but it was showing error (was using c#)

Comment: can you share your code?
I have implemented ViewBox and it works fine.

Comment: ViewBox works fine in case of Landscape/Fill/Portrait View but not in Snap View.. So if you are not trying to show anything in Snap View than this thing should resolve your issue.