# How to set text including new line character in storyboard

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

Want to replace "\n" with new line character

```
<VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Here is my text.\nThis is new line"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

The output text is: **`Here is my text.\nThis is new line`** 

without new line character.

**P.S.:** If this value can be filled with the string in resource file that would be a great..!!
Either way will help me out but later one is good approach.

Comment: Read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/xaml-newline-in-string-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing...

```
Value="Here is my text.&#10;This is new line"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to set this value from resource file like `x:Uid`?

Comment: You just want to store a string and apply like `Value="{StaticResource BlahText}"` instead? Making sure I understand lol.

Comment: The text is stored in `.resw` file not in standard resource

Comment: So, are you just looking for something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694557.aspx

Comment: Yes.. I know how to set `x:Uid` but don't know how to set in storyboard

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="20">

    <TextBlock.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="MyStory">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyLine1"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="New Line 1" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyLine2" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="New Line 2" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </TextBlock.Resources>

    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run x:Name="MyLine1" Text="Original Line 1" />
        <LineBreak />
        <Run x:Name="MyLine2" Text="Original Line 2" />
    </TextBlock.Inlines>

</TextBlock>
```

You could also try something like this without the `LineBreak`.

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="New Line 1&#x0a;" />
```